# private repo is getting cloned via ansible playbook but private gem are not getting installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ansible

I am using ansible for configuration management. I am cloning the private repo after copying the public and private key pair file to the remote server. The cloning is working fine but when I ran `bundle install`, getting error of `public key permission denied`.

> Ansible playbook

```
---
- hosts: launched
  sudo: yes
  remote_user: ubuntu
  key_file: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
  tasks:
  - name: update apt
    apt: update_cache=yes

  - name: ensure public key and public one are present
    sudo: yes
    copy: src={{item}} dest=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/{{ item }} mode=0600
    with_items:
      - id_rsa.pub

  - name: ensure private key and public one are present
    sudo: yes
    copy: src={{item}} dest=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/{{ item }} mode=0600
    with_items:
      - id_rsa

  - name: Deploy site files from Github repository
#    sudo: yes
    git: repo=git@github.com:xyz/abc.git dest=/home/{{deploy_user}}/{{app_name}} key_file=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa accept_hostkey=yes force=yes version=release
  - name: config database.yml
    template: src=database.yml.j2 dest={{ deploy_directory}}/config/database.yml

  - name: bundle install
    command: bundle install chdir={{ deploy_directory }}

  - name: sidekiq initializer
    command: bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml chdir={{deploy_directory}}

  - name: migrate create
    command: rake db:create RAILS_ENV="production" chdir={{ deploy_directory }}

  - name: migrate migrate
    command: rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production" chdir={{ deploy_directory }}
```

The Gemfile uses private gems via ssh url of gitub. Thus, while running the bundle install through playbook, getting the following error.

```
failed: [X.X.X.X] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["bundle", "install"], "delta": "0:00:05.788387", "end": "2015-11-03 06:39:43.671879", "rc": 11, "start": "2015-11-03 06:39:37.883492", "warnings": []}
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights.
```

The key I added to remote server also have access to private gem but somehow it is denying the permission.

I personally tried cloning the repo by ssh into the remote server but could not access the either repo(main repo and gem repo), though keys are being copied to `~/.ssh/` diretory of remote server.

> output of `ssh -vvv git@github.com`

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "github.com" from file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.30.252.130" from file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: could not open key file '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa': Permission denied
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: What error do you get from git when trying to clone locally? try using something like GIT_TRACE=2 git <command>, this is proably a problem in accessing github. also try ssh git@github.com which should give you back your username

Comment: @Srgrn I got the same error of permissione denied when I tried to clone the main repo as well as the private gem explicitly on the remote server

Comment: can you connect to the server and run ssh -vvv git@github.com and add the output?

Comment: @Srgrn See the update question for the output of `ssh -vvv git@github.com`

Answer (score 1):

youll notice that in the SSH output you have

```
 Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: could not open
 key file '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa': Permission denied debug1: Trying
 private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa debug3: no such identity:
 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory debug1: Trying
 private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa debug3: no such identity:
 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory debug1: Trying
 private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 debug3: no such identity:
 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
```

the first line says that current user doesn't have permission for id_rsa.

it seems you use sudo to copy the key which might set the ownership of the file to root instead of ubuntu.

change:

`copy: src={{item}} dest=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/{{ item }} mode=0600`

to:

`copy: src={{item}} dest=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/{{ item }} mode=0600 owner=ubuntu`

which according to ansible docs will be the user the file should be owned by

also you should put both files (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) in the same with items so it will run them in a loop

like:

```
 - name: ensure public key and public one are present
    sudo: yes
    copy: src={{item}} dest=/home/ubuntu/.ssh/{{ item }} mode=0600
    with_items:
      - id_rsa.pub
      - id_rsa
```